# Maclaurin expansion

Tags: analysis

$ f(x,y)=sin(x-2y)$

I have to expand this into Maclaurin series.

Of course I would like to use known series

$sinx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$

First of all, i treat $x$ as variable, and $y$ as parameter. We have that

$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y) = cos(x-2y)$

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x,y) = -sin(x-2y)$

$\frac{d^3}{dx^3}f(x,y) = -cos(x-2y)$

$\frac{d^4}{dx^4}f(x,y) = sin(x-2y)$

...

$\frac{d}{dx}f(0,0) = 1$

$\frac{d}{dx}f(0,0) = 0$

$\frac{d}{dx}f(0,0) = 1$

$\frac{d}{dx}f(0,0) = 0$

...

$y$ as variable, and $x$ as parameter. We have that

$\frac{d}{dy}f(x,y) = -2cos(x-2y)$

$\frac{d^2}{dy^2}f(x,y) = -4sin(x-2y)$

$\frac{d^3}{dy^3}f(x,y) = 8cos(x-2y)$

$\frac{d^4}{dy^4}f(x,y) = 16sin(x-2y)$

...

$\frac{d}{dy}f(0,0) = -2$

$\frac{d}{dy}f(0,0) = 0$

$\frac{d}{dy}f(0,0) = 8$

$\frac{d}{dy}f(0,0) = 0$

And what now? How I should write my series?

I think this

$sin(x-2y) = (\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!})$$( \sum_{l=0}^\infty (-1)^l\frac{y^{2l+1}}{(2l+1)!})$

is completly wrong. Give me some advice or just show me how to make it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to remember that

$$ \sin x = \sum \frac{ (-1)^n x^{2n+1} }{(2n+1)!} $$

and so

$$ \sin(x-2y) = \sum \frac{ (-1)^n (x-2y)^{2n+1} }{(2n+1)!} $$

One can expand further if  using the binomial

$$ (a+b)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} a^i b^{n-i} $$

Only a masochist would compute the partials..

Comment: LOL, and that is it? Why we don't use a double sum here? Edit: Because there is only one function, right?

Comment: Use binomial with $a=x$ and $b=-2y$